# Any possible ways to get Incoming or outgoing call numbers and all logs details?

Tags: ios, swift

I need to get all calls complete log details with duration and numbers with also detect that call is incoming or outgoing.

Can We detect incoming call or outgoing call?

Comment: No. An app cannot access that information without being jailbroken

Comment: Posting an actual bounty for this really displays a lack of how iOS has **always** been. Sorry.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can only get info about contacts, 
but no history, calls, sms, etc.
 Here's what you can do with Address book:

https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/ContactData/Conceptual/AddressBookProgrammingGuideforiPhone/Introduction.html

Anyway you can try this link

https://iosstuff.wordpress.com/2011/08/19/accessing-iphone-call-history/

Comment: I try your Solution and thanks for given your appropriate time

Answer (score 1):

i think apple provides this indirectly with callkit framework. please reffere this link [apple official doc](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/callkit)